# unable to parse xml with javascript loadXMLString()

Tags: php, javascript, xml, parsing, domparser

I am trying to parse the xml file from a webservice. I am using javascript loadXMLString function to parse the xml into html. with local file it was working fine if i insert the xml code in to a variable. but for getting xml from external link i have used php function here like this:

```
<?php 

$request = "http://www.somewebsite.com/feeds/get-cities.php?vendor_key=xxx";
$response = file_get_contents($request);
$xmlstring =  htmlspecialchars($response, ENT_QUOTES);
?>
<script language="javascript">
function loadXMLString(txt)  
{
if (window.DOMParser)
{
  parser=new DOMParser();
  xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(txt,"text/xml");
}
else // Internet Explorer
{
  xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmlDoc.async=false;
  xmlDoc.loadXML(txt); 
}
return xmlDoc;
}//function loadXMLString ends

text = <?php $xmlstring;?>

xmlDoc=loadXMLString(text);


document.write("<table border='1'>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("city");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{ 
  document.write("<tr style='background:#dddddd;'><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("country")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td></tr>");
}
document.write("</table>");
</script>
```

in the above code i am trying to insert the xml code from a php variable $xmlstring to javascript variable text. but it display nothing. but if i put the xml code inside the script like below it works perfectly:

```
text="<cities>"
text=text+"<city>";
text=text+"<name>bulga</name>";
text=text+"<country>Giada De Laurentiis</country>";
text=text+"<city_id>2005</city_id>";
text=text+"</city>";
text=text+"</cities>";
```

does any body know how can i parse it. or if somebody have a better solution please suggest me that also.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change following line in your code

```
text = <?php echo $xmlstring;?>
```

it should echo your variable value.

Comment: is it necessary to parse XML into javascript only ? you can parse xml into php and then make your html ?

Comment: ys i have parsed it through php also but its having problem when we need to filter the result on webpage accordingly different category. then its need to do this thing with javascript because javascript is client side and can do the things easily while cliking on button.


let me show u what i want to do, check this link here u can see how the left side filter btns working

http://www.trivago.com

go to this site and search for hotel and u can see some filter buttons for result

Comment: can you get alert(text) in loadXMLString function ?

Comment: can you echo xmlstring just after htmlspecialchars line ? paste the result ?

Comment: ys that is displaying the xml string like this

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><cities><city><city_id>8130</city_id><country>SPAIN</country><name>A Pontenova</name><establishment_count>1</establishment_count></city><city><city_id>556</city_id><country>UNITED KINGDOM</country><name>Aberdeen</name><establishment_count>1</establishment_count></city><city><city_id>7239</city_id><country>ITALY</country><name>Abetone</name><establishment_count>1</establishment_count></city></cities>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16922/discussion-between-harish-kumar-and-gbd)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of GBD i have written the following code and its start displaying the city list. but when i try this with different xml code it does not work. may be someone have better solution for this

```
<?php 
function curl_get_file_contents($URL) 
{ 
$c = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $URL); 
$contents = curl_exec($c); 
curl_close($c); 

if ($contents) return $contents; 
else return FALSE; 
} 

$xmlString = curl_get_file_contents("http://www.somesite.com/feeds/get-cities.php?vendor_key=xxx");

?>

<script language="javascript">
function loadXMLString(text) 
{ 
if (window.DOMParser) 
{ 
parser=new DOMParser(); 
xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml"); 
} 
else // Internet Explorer 
{ 
xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM"); 
xmlDoc.async=false; 
xmlDoc.loadXML(text);  
} 
return xmlDoc; 
}

var text = "<?php echo substr_replace($xmlString,"",0,39);?>";


xmlDoc=loadXMLString(text);


document.write("<table border='1'>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("city");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{ 
document.write("<tr style='background:#dddddd;'><td>");
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write("</td><td>");
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("country")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write("</td></tr>");
}
document.write("</table>");
</script>
```